# Remove Tag Cloud Words from Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

How can I remove the `Seperate tags with commas` and `Choose from the most used tags` from my custom taxonomy?  These: [image]

My Current registration for it is:

```
$labels = array('name' => 'Company', 
    'popular_items' => NULL);
register_taxonomy('test_company', 'testimonials', 
    array('show_tagcloud' => false, 
        'hierarchical' => false, 
        'labels' => $labels, 
        'query_var' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => false));
```

Comment: I had purged comment since the thread was clearly going in less than civil direction. Please remember to be polite on either side of the conversation. There is no need to be hostile to people for question perceived as lacking. From the other side if people have trouble understanding the question it very well might _be_ the question and not them. I recommend to clarify title and display image inline rather than link to third party service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to remove the words: `Seperate tags with commas` and `Choose from the most used tags`

Simply add to the labels the following:

```
'choose_from_most_used' => NULL,
'separate_items_with_commas' => NULL,
```